# How get specific elememt that have data-bind attribute and call now (using now-active now)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, data-binding, knockout.js

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="well" data-id="myApp">

        // Data-Bind is Here
        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control input-sm" 
               data-bind="value:name,valueUpdate:'afterkeyup'" />
        // Data-Bind is Here


        <p class="info" data-bind="text:name"></p>

        <button class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click:showName">Show</button>

    </div>

</div>
```

I want to get html element that have "data-bind" attribute for example I want to Get something like this :

```
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control input-sm" 
               data-bind="value:name,valueUpdate:'afterkeyup'" />
```

if I change above code like this :

```
<div class="container">

        // Data-Bind is HERE Now
        <div class="well" data-id="myApp" data-bind="value:name,valueUpdate:'afterkeyup'">
        // Data-Bind is HERE Now

            <input type="text" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />

            <p class="info" data-bind="text:name"></p>

            <button class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click:showName">Show</button>

        </div>

    </div>
```

now I want to get element like this :

```
<div class="well" data-id="myApp" data-bind="value:name,valueUpdate:'afterkeyup'">
```

How can I have function for get active element that set data-bind for it , when data-bind read I can get correspondingly element of it

I need general way not for specific event or ...

Comment: use the [has attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector

Comment: Waht do you mean by 'active' data-bind element ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all elements with a `data-bind` attribute with the jquery attribute selector.

```
$("*[data-bind]")
```

Next you can refine the selector in various ways, e.g. to consider only certain tags or choosing only a slice of the result,or by employing jquery filters:

```
$("div[data-bind], input[data-bind], p.data-carrier[data-bind]"); // consider only div, input, or  p elements, the latter only when having class data-carrier
$("*[data-bind]:first"); // use the first match only
$("*[data-bind]")[1];  // use  the second match only
$("*[data-bind]").filter(":even"); // use only matches with an even index  in the list of matches
$("*[data-bind]").each ( function ( idx, element ) { /* your code */ } ); // the most general approach: iterate through the results and decide upon each element what to do next
```

Comment: no no Its my mistake I need only active data-bind element

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery then you can use ["has attribute" selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/). For example:

```
$("[data-bind]")
```

Comment: no no Its my mistake I need only active data-bind element

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what do you mean by saying "active element". Could you explain more detailed or rephrase this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this in jquery:

```
var elem = $('.container').find('[data-bind]');
```

Comment: no no Its my mistake I need only active data-bind element

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("*[data-bind]")[0].outerHTML`

It will you the `outerHTML` of the element.

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0q5nszz/)**